# How to specify number of leaf or terminal nodes in decision tree in R

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree, party

Is there a way to limited maximum nodes or tree complexity using party package in **R**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up [the documentation for the `party` package, one page of which describes how to limit the depth](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf#page=10) (using the `maxdepth` parameter).

Hope this helps!